# No despliega campo con ForeignKey Base de datos Mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, relaciones

Favor me pueden ayudar con el siguiente problema al generar unas tablas `mysql`

Tengo la tabla `tipologia_productividad` con su respectiva id y la tabla `planosTipologia` donde tengo su id y un campo llamado `tipologia_id` que quiero hacerlo `foreign Key` de la id de la tabla `tipologia_productividad`.

Todo esto me funciona pero al ir a phpmyadmin me doy cuenta de que al intentar insertar un nuevo plano este no me despliega la lista de las tipologias sino que me muestra un campo de texto donde yo debo ingresar manualmente el campo (permitiendo la inserción incorrecta de información).

Código:

```
CREATE TABLE tipologia_productividad (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE planosTipologia (
  id bigint(11) NOT NULL ,
  tipologia_id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
);

ALTER TABLE tipologia_productividad
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE planosTipologia
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
  ADD KEY tipologia_id (tipologia_id);

ALTER TABLE tipologia_productividad
  MODIFY id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE planosTipologia
  MODIFY id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE planosTipologia
ADD CONSTRAINT partida_tipologia_id_foreign
FOREIGN KEY(tipologia_id)
REFERENCES tipologia_productividad(id);
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo haría las siguientes correcciones

Para crear la tabla principal o que tiene la `PK` sería de este modo

```
CREATE TABLE tipologia_productividad (
  id bigint(20) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
);
```

**OBSERVACIONES**

1. Quito el atributo `NOT NULL`
2. Agrego dentro de la misma declaración de la tabla los atributos `PRIMARY KEY` y `AUTO_INCREMENT`
3. No veo necesario el agregar los atributos anteriormente mencionados por separado por medio de la sintaxis de `ALTER TABLE ....`

Para crear la tabla dependiente o que tiene la `FK` sería de este modo

```
CREATE TABLE planosTipologia (
  id bigint(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  tipologia_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_planosTipologia_tipologia_productividad FOREIGN KEY(tipologia_id) 
  REFERENCES tipologia_productividad(id)
);
```

**OBSERVACIONES**

1. La llave foránea la agrego por medio de un `CONSTRAINT`
2. Por medio de `FOREIGN KEY()` agrego la columna que va a actuar como llave foránea
3. Por medio de `REFERENCES` indico la tabla y la columna con la cual haré la vinculación

Comment: Efectivamente funciona lo que me envías muchas gracias!